# Return all tables and views used in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2005

I want to see what tables and views are used in a stored procedure by only giving the stored procedure name.

Can this be done and if so how does one do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [sp_depends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx)

```
sp_depends 'sp_name'
```

---

Displays information about database object dependencies, such as the views and procedures that depend on a table or view, **and the tables and views that are depended on by the view or procedure**. References to objects outside the current database are not reported.

Comment: sp_depends is set to be deprecated, and worse can return incorrect results if objects are created out of order. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Management Studio, you can also right click on the stored procedure and select "View Dependencies."  There's a toggle switch to view objects that depend on the procedure or objects on which the procedure depends.